# How to draw an hierarchical tree using graphstream

Tags: java, graphstream

This is my code and the output is not in the form of an hierarchical tree

```java
public class Simple {
        
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Graph graph = new SingleGraph("Test");

        Viewer viewer = graph.display(false);
        HierarchicalLayout hl = new HierarchicalLayout();
        viewer.enableAutoLayout(hl);
        graph.setStrict(false);
        graph.setAutoCreate(false); 
        graph.addNode("A" );        
        graph.addNode("B" );
        graph.addNode("C" );
        graph.addNode("D");
        graph.addNode("E");


        graph.getNode("A").addAttribute("ui.label", "A");
        graph.getNode("B").addAttribute("ui.label", "B");
        graph.addEdge("A-B", "A", "B",true);
        graph.addEdge("A-C", "A", "C",true);
        graph.addEdge("B-D", "B", "D",true);
        graph.addEdge("B-E", "B", "E",true);
```

The nodes are placed randomly even though I used the hierarchical layout.

I am trying to draw a tree as seen in the following picture:

[image].

Comment: Did you ever manage to visualize a tree properly?